# Failure of pipelines deployed to a trigger at same time?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

There is a trigger set to run pipelines at 5 AM.

```
Pipeline name: 5_AM_Trigger
Pipelines running on trigger: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B
```

I was working on Pipeline_C and another developer is working on Pipeline_D. We ended up deploying to same trigger around same time.

Deployment made to trigger by me:

```
Before deployment: 
Pipelines on trigger: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B

After deployment:
Pipelines on trigger: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B, Pipeline_C
```

Deployment made to trigger by another Developer(few minutes after my deployment):

```
Before deployment: 
Pipelines on trigger: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B 

After deployment:
Pipelines on trigger: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B, Pipeline_D
```

The reason I got to know that why Pipeline_C did not appear in the trigger because another developer did not do a browser refresh after my deployment and ended up adding his Pipeline to Previous trigger configurations(2 pipelines) overwriting trigger with new configurations(3 pipelines).

Is this a valid reason? If yes Is there a solution for this issue?

```
Expected pipelines on trigger after both deployments: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B, Pipeline_C, Pipeline_D
Actual pipelines on trigger after both deployments: Pipeline_A, Pipeline_B, Pipeline_D
```

Comment: Do you set the trigger in the yaml file in Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxx)? Generally, the trigger is set in each yaml file, Pipeline_C and Pipeline_D should not effect each other, could you show us how do you set the trigger? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have trigger created in adf.azure.com -> Manage -> Triggers -> Create+New -> then entered details for trigger Name, description, schedule, recuurance, etc and activated. After that adf.azure.com -> Author -> Pipeline ->Trigger -> New/Edit -> Selected the name of trigger that was already created and then -> Validate -> Validate All -> published

This worked since lot of pipelines are running on triggers created a while ago but this issue occurs only when two people deploy pipelines to same trigger at same time when one pipeline overrides other without getting recent changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish in live mode of data factory (When not connected to GIT) is same as save option. When other person works on stale copy and publishes the changes on same components worked by others, it is expected to overwrite those changes.

To avoid this, when multiple team members are working on a project, suggested approach is to use GIT mode where separate branches can be used by all and publish can be done from collaboration branch once all changes are merged.

Comment: can you add some more information on your answer or any links i can take a look at?